# What cards have good potential for a combo with Mayor of Avabruck // Howlpack Alpha?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

In the Innistrad set, at least 1 of the double faced cards is a werewolf with the ability to upgrade other werewolves and wolves in play.  What other wolves have good potential to combine with the Mayor of Avabruck//Howlpack Alpha card?

I'm thinking primarily of Commander games, but if you think something fits a different format, please note that.

[image: Mayor of Avabruck // Howlpack Alpha]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why settle for two or three wolves when you can have seven or more of them instead?

[image: Howl of the Night Pack]

Answer (score 4):

If just having a ton of 3/3 wolves isn't enough for you - why not have them fall upon your opponent's creatures like, er, a pack of wolves?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

With Howlpack Alpha, you get a free creature token every turn for zero mana. It's crying out for a Juniper Order Ranger.

[image: Juniper Order Ranger]

That guy's going to get large. So now you're getting a lot of creatures with counters on them. Maybe they're still too small… And maybe you still don't have enough of them…

[image: Plaguemaw Beast] [image: Doubling Season]

**EDIT:** Just a note on how insane Doubling Season is…

- Howlpack Alpha + Doubling Season = two effectively 3/3 wolves every turn
- add J.O. ranger = two effectively 5/5 wolves every turn, ranger grows +2/+2 each turn
- add Plaguemaw Beast = Sac. a wolf to grow all other wolves and ranger +2/+2

Answer (score 2):

Here are some ways of generating more wolf tokens to play a swarming strategy.

[image: Fable of Wolf and Owl][image: Turntimber Ranger]

This kicker might be more appropriate to EDH/Commander games where mana is more plentiful, likewise Master of the Hunt is expensive but if mana is plentiful, it might be an option.

[image: Wolfbriar Elemental][image: Master of the Hunt]

For true EDH play, here's your general for this deck:

[image: Rhys the Redeemed]

Comment: Note that Master of the Hunt has errata on him so that the tokens he produces are Wolf tokens _named_ Wolves of the Hunt; previously, since they had no specified creature type, their type was the same as their name and they wouldn't have gotten the Alpha's bonus!

Answer (score 2):

These cards have Human and Wolf or Warewolf in their creature types, and would gain +1/+1 from the Mayor regardless of which face was up.

[image: Gatstaf Shepherd//Gatstaf Howler][image: Grizzled Outcasts//Krallenhorde Wantons]

These (formerly human wolf) cards are (now, Sept 2011) werewolves and benefit when Howlpack Alpha is face up.

[image: Treacherous Werewolf][image: Lesser Werewolf][image: Greater Werewolf]

Comment: +1 for the cool factor of getting the bonus from either face of the Mayor/Alpha, even if it's not exactly the most powerful combo!

Comment: Options for the Green/Black player :)

Comment: Garruk Relentless doesn't technically ever require black mana to play, but he'd look pretty cool as a "champion" for the G/B Werewolf deck nonetheless...

Comment: I'd be surprised if the old black Werewolf cards weren't errata'd to be just of the Werewolf type, to be consistent with the back face of the double-faced Werewolves.

Comment: Pack's Disdain and Cover of Darkness would also fit very nicely into a thematic G/B werewolves deck...

Comment: This answer will no longer be entirely correct once [these Oracle change](http://www.wizards.com/Magic/Magazine/Article.aspx?x=mtg/daily/feature/161d&page=2) come into effect later today. Lesser/Greater Werewolf is now a Werewolf, and Treacherous Werewolf is now a Wolf Werewolf Minion.

Answer (score 1):

Metal wolf!  Not only does he get the boost from the Mayor/Alpha, he also boosts the Mayor/Alpha if you set his type to Werewolf.  It's a win/win partnership!

(I've noticed that Pat has requested that we amalgamate our answers into one decisive one, so my final answer is this guy plus the two other cards I've posted so far.  A pretty good start to creating a nasty pumped-up werewolf package.)

[image: Adaptive Automaton][image: Brass Herald]

Comment: Another great card that should be included.  The collection of answers is strongly suggesting an interesting deck.

Comment: Brass Herald is another artifact "lord" that can give all Werewolves +1/+1... unfortunately this one is much less of a bargain at cc 6!  Door of Destinies might be worth a look, if you can accommodate the idea of wolves having destinies of course...

Answer (score -2):

[image]
[image]
[image]

These cards if played in order shown will get you twice many wolves as you have land on top of the wolves from your howlpack alpha and however many wolves you have played after door of destinys comes into play they get pumped. I had 80 80/80 wolves after i used one howl of the night pack and one reverberate.

Comment: How does Door of Destinies get any charge counters here? You need to play a Wolf spell for it to get a charge counter, playing Howl of the Night Pack won't give you any charge counters.